# Yii JavaScript window-like widget that is movable/swappable and has minimize and maximize buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, widget, yii-extensions

I would ask for help to point to me a yii widget that will allow me to have several window-like widgets in a page.

Wherein, the window could be drag, minimize, maximize. I have researched other widgets that are draggable but do not have the minimize and maximize buttons.

Below is the image to what I like to have.

[image]